# How to efficiently find period orbits in a series defined by recurrence relation?

Tags: list-manipulation, fractals

I have a series defined as

$z_{n+1} = z_n^2 + c$, which is the series for the [Mandelbrot set](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MandelbrotSet.html).

I have defined it, in order to plot the set, as

```
Zn[c_, n_][z0_] := Nest[((#)^2 + c) &, z0, n];
```

Now, I'd like to find its periodic orbits.

If $Z_{n(p)} == Z_{m(p)}$, then $\{Z_n, ..., Z_{m-1}\}$ is a periodic orbit of period $m-n$.

How do I find them in *Mathematica* in a computationally reasonable way?

I tried building a brute force sieve that accepts $\{Z_0, ..., Z_{\tt{nMax}}\}$ as inputs and just searches for $Z_i, Z_j$ s.t. $| Z_i - Z_j | < \epsilon$, like:

```
OrbitsSieve[orbitTable_] := Module[{},
   positionDuplicates[list_] := 
    GatherBy[Range@Length[list], list[[#]] &];
   PeriodicOrbits[zList_] := Map[
     {#[[1]], #[[2]] - #[[1]]} &,
     Map[
      {#[[
         1]], #[[2]]} &, 
      Select[positionDuplicates[Round[zList*100]/100], Length[#] > 2 &]
      ]
     ];
   Map[
    orbitTable[[#]] &,
    Map[Range[#[[1]], #[[1]] + #[[2]] - 1] &, 
     PeriodicOrbits[orbitTable]]
    ]
   ];
```

However, this:

1. Is only an approximate solution
2. Is slow as molasses
3. Sucks.

Is there a better, faster, more elegant, algebraic or analytic way of doing it?

Thanks.

Comment: You might want to look up cycle detection algorithms, such as the ones by Floyd or Brent. I coded up something I called `CycleFixedPoint[]` using these, but I do not have access to the associated notebooks at this time.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis: thanks. I'm gonna read up on the subject. *However*, I have reason to suspect there is an easier way (it's a small part of a bigger lab assignment and I *guess* the prof would have clued us).

Comment: @Guesswhoitis: from what I read about Floyd and Brent neither eliminates the problem of floating point error and necessary approximation, though - or do they?

Comment: Well, part of the deal would involve using a slightly fuzzier equality criterion for cycle detection. Say, "equal up to ten digits"…

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. I think the definition of fuzziness is an important point here. Mandelbrot set has infinite amount of points near the boundary which seem to follow an orbit, only to diverge after arbitrarily high number of steps. So, what is the goal of recognizing these fuzzy orbits?

Comment: For modest period lengths it can be handled as an algebraic system e.g. `Solve[z==f[f[z,c],c], z]`.